# DONE Python Pandas: sum() adds int values in data frame as string instead of integers

Tags: python, pandas

My problem seems very simple but I can't find answer for that.
I am trying to use sum() in pandas to calculate how many women and men are attempting suicide in Albania base on dataset from kaggle.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

#Create a dataframe
suicide = pd.read_csv('who_suicide_statistics.csv', header=None)

#Rename column names because it was int
suicide = suicide.rename(columns={0: 'country', 1: 'year', 2: 'sex', 3: 'age', 4:'suicides_no', 5: 'population'})
#Delete first row because it was a duplicate with column names
suicide = suicide.iloc[1: , :]

#Filter values only with Albania
albania_suicide = suicide.loc[(suicide['country'] == 'Albania')]

#Delete rows with Nan values
albania_suicide.dropna(subset=['suicides_no'], inplace=True)

# Is it more women or men who attempts suicide?
print(albania_suicide.loc[albania_suicide['sex'] == 'female', 'suicides_no'].sum())
```

And the output is:

```
"144600185403252701074201010771206420121378222161091122116760232109160191351646350029412262147151411491309620111733300000000000013814093209191750000006612272"
```

And these are numbers are display one by one as if they were treated like a string.
It should be 14 + 4 + 6 + 0 + 0 + 18 ....

Comment: I would assume you need to convert whatever column to a number type. However, I don't see where you call `sum` nor do I know what your data looks like so this is only a guess.

Comment: I edited the question, now you can see where I am using sum()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this? Its hard to know why you are concatenating instead of summing without that line of code.

```
total = df['suicides_no'].astype(int).sum()
```

Comment: it gives me an output like I mentioned in the question :/

Comment: @ZuzannaKilar what about with how I just updated it?

Comment: @ZuzannaKilar don't forget to pick which answer you like best.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `suicides_no` column is of string type (strings of numbers).  If you are sure the values should be all numeric, you can try, e.g.

```
df['suicides_no'].astype(int).sum()
```

or permanently convert your datatype to int before your code to sum it:

```
df['suicides_no'] = df['suicides_no'].astype(int)

# then sum
df['suicides_no'].sum()
```